# C++ std::atomic - impossibility of synchronizing 2 threads based on a shared atomic variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, atomic

In my program, 2 threads sort a simple array in a contradictory (**for test**) way. The single idea is to prevent both threads to sort the array **at the same time using std::atomic**. The expected result is that the array will be sorted, either descending or ascending depending on "the winner thread".
**I know that this can easily be solved with mutexes**, but I just here try to understand the benefit of std::atomic. My program fails in 10% of all execution cases: failure is when both sorts intertwine... Thanks in advance for any highlighting...

```
    std::array<int, 5> my_array{ 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 };
    std::atomic< std::array<int, 5>* > my_array_{ &my_array };

    std::thread my_thread(
        [&my_array_]() {
            std::array<int, 5>* my_array = nullptr;
            do { my_array = my_array_.load(std::memory_order_acquire); } while (my_array == nullptr);
            my_array_.store(nullptr, std::memory_order_release);

            std::sort(my_array->begin(), my_array->end(),
                [](const int a, const  int b) {
                    // std::cout << "\tascending a: " << a << " b: " << b << std::endl;
                    return a > b;
                });
            my_array_.store(my_array, std::memory_order_release);
        });

    std::thread my_thread_(
        [&my_array_]() {
            std::array<int, 5>* my_array = nullptr;
            do { my_array = my_array_.load(std::memory_order_acquire); } while (my_array == nullptr);
            my_array_.store(nullptr, std::memory_order_release);

            std::sort(my_array->begin(), my_array->end(),
                [](const int a, const int b) {
                    // std::cout << "\tdescending a: " << a << " b: " << b << std::endl;
                    return a < b;
                });
            my_array_.store(my_array, std::memory_order_release);
        });

    my_thread_.join();
    my_thread.join();

    for (const int i : my_array)
        std::cout << "\t" << i;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `my_array_` atomic variable to indicate whether some thread has claimed it, then you can simply call

`auto local_array=my_array_.exchange(nullptr)`

from your threads. `local_array` will thus be a pointer to `my_array` if this is the first thread to do the exchange, and `nullptr` if the other thread got there first.

As it stands, with the plain loads and stores, then both threads can read the `my_array_` pointer and see that it is not `nullptr`, then both can store `nullptr` in it, and both think they got there first.

Also: Using `my_array` for the name of the global, *and* the name of the local pointer is asking for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

According to Anthony's remarks, here is a solution (some changes in variable naming for better distinction):

````
std::array<int, 5> my_array{ 1, 4, 3, 2, 5 };
std::atomic< std::array<int, 5>* > my_atomic{ &my_array };

    std::thread ascending(
        [&my_atomic]() {
            // Resource is unavailable:
            std::array<int, 5>* my_array = nullptr;
            // Race condition, try to be the first to get the resource:
            do { my_array = my_atomic.exchange(nullptr); } while (my_array == nullptr);
            std::sort(my_array->begin(), my_array->end(),
                [](const int a, const int b) {
                    // std::cout << "\tascending a: " << a << " b: " << b << std::endl;
                    return a > b;
                });
            // Release resource:
            my_atomic.exchange(my_array);
        });

    std::thread descending(
        [&my_atomic]() {
            // Resource is unavailable:
            std::array<int, 5>* my_array = nullptr;
            // Race condition, try to be the first to get the resource:
            do { my_array = my_atomic.exchange(nullptr); } while (my_array == nullptr);
            std::sort(my_array->begin(), my_array->end(),
                [](const int a, const int b) {
                    // std::cout << "\tdescending a: " << a << " b: " << b << std::endl;
                    return a < b;
                });
            // Release resource:
            my_atomic.exchange(my_array);
        });

    descending.join();
    ascending.join();

    for (const int i : my_array) // Either ascending or descending based on the "loser thread"
        std::cout << "\t" << i;```
````